# Proximal operator for an $L$-smooth but nonconvex function

Tags: convex-analysis, non-convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Proximal operator definition is:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{prox}_{\eta f}(x) := \arg\min_{z} \ \eta f(z) + \frac{1}{2}\| z - x \|_2^2,
\end{align}
where typically $f$ is assumed to be closed convex proper function.

To this end, let $f$ be an $L$-smooth function, i.e., $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \| \leq L \|x-y\|, \ \forall x,y \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$. Then, in this [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2021/file/fe7ee8fc1959cc7214fa21c4840dff0a-Paper.pdf) (page 4), it states that if $0 < \eta < \frac{1}{L}$ the proximal operator of such a function is **well-defined and single-valued**.

My question is about this "well-defined and single-valued".
**Can we say the following is valid for such a smooth nonconvex function as well?**
\begin{align}
p = \operatorname{prox}_{\eta f}(x) \Longleftrightarrow x - p = \eta \nabla f(x).
\end{align}

If not, then can someone please enlighten me what does "well-defined and single-valued" mean then?

Comment: Yes, what you write is valid. It follows from the fact that for the given range of $\eta$, the "inner" function $z \mapsto \eta f(z) + \frac{1}{2} \|z - x\|^2$ is strongly convex in $z$.

Comment: @VHarisop Thank you for the clarification